# Having One Listener Trigger Two Different Methods

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and was wondering how I could have one listener call two different methods.

The following is my code:

```
class Round extends ChangeNotifier {
    void launchHand() {
        _currentIndex = 0;

        incrementHandNo();

        notifyListeners();
    }

    void changeTurn() {
        _currentIndex = _currentIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class _BoardViewState extends State<BoardView> {

    void newHandHasBegun() {
   
        showDialogPopUp(context, "New Hand",
            "A new hand has begun.\nYou will play first.");
    }

    void _playerTakesTurn() {

        _otherPlayer = getOtherPlayer(players, widget.roundController.currentIndex);

        List<Tile> tileToPlaceAndStack = widget.board.recommendATileToPlace(
            players[widget.roundController.currentIndex], _otherPlayer);

        _tileToPlace = tileToPlaceAndStack[0];
        _tileOnTopOfStack = tileToPlaceAndStack[1];

        if (_tileToPlace.getTileFace() == "" ||
            _tileOnTopOfStack.getTileFace() == "" && passCount == 0) {
            passCount++;
        } else if (_tileToPlace.getTileFace() == "" ||
            _tileOnTopOfStack.getTileFace() == "" && passCount == 1) {
            widget.roundController.launchHand();
        }
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _playerTakesTurn());

        widget.roundController.launchHand();

        if (players[widget.roundController.currentIndex].getPlayerName() ==
            "Human") {
            widget.humanPlayer.enableTileTapsInHumansHand();
        }

        widget.roundController.addListener(_playerTakesTurn);
    }
}
```

When widget.roundController.launchHand() is executed, instead of the _playerTakesTurn() method, I want the newHandHasBegun() method to be called. How can I make this happen?
Do I need to declare two different listeners that call two different methods?

Comment: You want to call the two methods on the same event or call once a method and once the other method, based on some logic?

Comment: Hi. I want to call once a method and once the other method based on some logic. So if the changeTurn() method is called, I want the _playerTakesTurn() method to be triggered., whereas if the launchHand() method is called, I want the newHandHasBegin() method to be triggered.